# Android USBAccessory reconnecting

Tags: android, usb, accessory

I have a problem with reconnecting to an USB accessory after it has been plugged off and on again. The first time the accessory is plugged in I am able to do all the steps to actually communicate with the device

1. Enumerate the accessory
2. Get permission to access the accessory
3. Open the accessory
4. Read and write with to the device with the FileDescriptor's I/O streams

When I plug off the cable and plug it in again, I am able to complete the first two steps listed above. The problem is that the UsbManager's open accessory returns null as the ParcelFileDescriptor. What could cause this? Could it be that, some resources still reserved and therefore the Android can't grant me access to the device? I am releasing the I/O streams and closing the ParcelFileDescriptor before calling the openAccessory. Is there still something else that should be done to properly clean up with the accessory? The official documentation page about USB accessories has a section about terminating the communication, but it is not very helpful.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html